# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>' (TS2769)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some element like below that uses concat but getting error with

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(...items:
> ConcatArray[]): never[]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.
> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ConcatArray': length, join, slice   Overload 2 of 2,
> '(...items: ConcatArray[]): never[]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.  TS2

```
const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <Bar>
      {someArrayOfComponents.concat(
        <AnotherComponent />
      )}
    </Box>
  )
})
```